# Python: Most efficient way to find if circles whos centre coordinates are from a numpy.random array overlap with other circles in array?

Tags: python, computational-geometry

So I've got a random array of the centre-point coordinates of circles in 2D, of variable radius r. I need to create a function that determines whether a given circle overlaps with another. Obviously, if their separation in either dimension is less than 2r they overlap. I've created a function to do this:

```
          def x_overlap(n,r):
              radius_arr=array([2*r,2*r,2*r,2*r,2*r,2*r,2*r,2*r,2*r,2*r])
              diff_in_x=x-x[n]
              x_touch=radius_arr-diff_in_x
              for item in x_touch:
                  if item<0:
                      return "disk of ” n “ index overlaps with disk of ” x_touch.index(item) “ index in x direction"
                  else:
                      return "no overlaps for disk of ” n “ index in x direction"

          def y_overlap(n,r):
              radius_arr=array([2*r,2*r,2*r,2*r,2*r,2*r,2*r,2*r,2*r,2*r])
              diff_in_y=y-y[n]
              y_touch=radius_arr-diff_in_y
              for item in y_touch:
                  if item<0:
                      return "disk of “ n “ index overlaps with disk of ” y_touch.index(item) “ index in y direction"
                  else:
                      return "no overlaps for disk of “ n “ index in y direction"
          def overlap(n,r):
              return x_overlap(n,r) + " " + "and" + " " + y_overlap(n,r)
```

I've had a few problems with this code; first of all, its very long. Second of all, the n's and y_touch.index(item) references do not appear in the console when I run the function. Whats wrong with the code I've got and is there a better way of doing it?

Thank you!

Comment: You can solve this using `numpy` arrays. This will allow you to do all the distance calculations at once in a very optimized way. Then it just comes to finding where this distance is less than the radius.

Comment: @sean can you be more specific? What do I do?
I've tried to do this with the code I've got, but I can't get the indices into the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Check to see if the distance between the center points is less than than the sum of the radii:

```
def is_overlap(circle1, circle2):
    distance = ((circle1.x - circle2.x)**2 + (circle1.y - circle2.y)**2)**0.5

    return distance < circle1.r + circle2.r
```

Your code won't work for circles positioned something like this (your code really treats the circles like squares):

```
 o
o
```

Comment: But the radius is meant to be a variable and the circles are based on random points generated by a 2xN array, and the code should take all of the coordinates (one at a time is fine and the code can be run multiple times) and compare them with the other coordinates in the array to see if there are any overlaps.

Comment: @user1934426: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you trying to generate a bunch of non-overlapping circles?

Comment: The radius should be an argument of the function, since it should be able to be changed at any point. Also, the coordinates of the centres of the circles are stored in a numpy.random array - the function is supposed to test whether any of these circles overlap.

Comment: @user1934426: Sorry, I still can't understand what you're trying to say here. Why is the radius an argument? Can you explain *exactly* what you're trying to do?

Comment: Basically, numpy.random generates an array of random 2D coordinates. These coordinates are the centrepoints of circles in 2D space with a radius r (the radius can be any number - part of the purpose of the code is to change the radius and see how that affects how many circles overlap, etc). Basically, I need to write a code that determines if any of these circles overlap, and which ones overlap, and then add each set of connected circles to different dictionaries.

Comment: @user1934426: So how doesn't my code solve your problem? If `r` is fixed, then just replace `circle1.r + circle2.r` with `2 * r` and you're good to go.

Comment: It solves the actual problem, but it doesn't return which if any coordinates in the array it would overlap with. Like, ideally it would return the index of the circle it overlaps with, and tehn it would define this group of circles as a list.